# assign a product attribute value to another product attribute in magento

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, magento

i have a `Weight` attribute :

```
Attribute Code: weight
Scope: general
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Text Field
Values Required: yes
Apply To: Simple Product, Bundle Product
Allow HTML Tags on Frontend: yes
```

and i have a `General Weight` attribute :

```
Attribute Code: general_weight
Scope: general
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Text Field
Values Required: no
Apply To: All Product Types
Use in Advanced Search: yes
Comparable on Front-end: yse
Allow HTML Tags on Frontend: yes
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end: yes
```

i want to assign `Weight` attribute to `General Weight` without four decimals. i mean i want the value of `Weight` attribute( for example 2000.0000 to copy into `General Weight` value on product save (but without for last decimals like 2000).

**i made an small extension for that in this way:**

i created `Moh3n_Attvaluecopier.xml` file in `app/etc/modules` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and `config.xml` file in `app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/etc` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Moh3n_Attvaluecopier>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <moh3nattvaluecopier>
                <class>Attvaluecopier_Model</class>
            </moh3nattvaluecopier>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>copyAttribute</method>
                    </moh3n_attvaluecopier_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

and `Observer.php` file in `app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/model` with this content:

```
<?php

class Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer
{

private $_processFlag; //to prevent infinite loop of event-catch situation
public function  copyAttribute($observer){

    if(!$this->_processFlag):

    $this->_processFlag=true;
    $_store = $observer->getStoreId();
    $_product = $observer->getProduct();
    $_productid = $_product->getId();

    $attrA = $_product->getAttributeText('weight'); //get attribute A's value

    $action = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action');
    $action->updateAttributes(array($_productid), array('general_weight'=>$attrWeight),$_store); //assign attrA's value to attrB
    $_product->save();
    endif;}
}
```

i fill `weight` attribute with some numbers like `2000.0000` but nothing is going to change in `General Weight` after saving product. i mean the value `2000` won't copy to `General Weight` attribute and `General Weight` won't show any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated observer function :

```
<?php

public function  copyAttribute($observer){

    if(!$this->_processFlag):

    $this->_processFlag=true;
    $_product = $observer->getProduct();
    $_productid = $_product->getId();
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $loadCurrentProduct = $productModel->load($_productid);
    $loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight(intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight()));
    $loadCurrentProduct->save();
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in app/code/local/Moh3n/Attvaluecopier/Model/Observer.php on line 3 . this error came up with your code.

Comment: I have just modified the function, you need to replace it in your previous function. I think you have skipped mentioning class and your private variable which you have declared before your function

Comment: @MihirBhende Somewhat same question but for magento 2. plz have a look and suggest, I am really stuck in this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339316/error-while-loading-product-using-id-magento-2-4